# Safe navigation at v-model directive in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For example we have the following input component:

```
 <input type="text" v-model="example.modules.report.description.title"></input>
```

[Full source](https://jsfiddle.net/j64perwL/)

I don't want to define in `data` following object:

```
example: {
  modules: {
    report: {
      description: {
         title: ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I anticipate that Vue.js will create that structure itself (just like Angular.js), but it doesn't do it.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

the data() method is a factory that initializes the model on which the component is bound.

The docs explains clearly how is supposed to make it work

> You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

[vuejs docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components)

If your model is so complex to require all these nested compositions maybe you have to be fine with it or design a different data model.......or create your model with your own factory

```
export default {
    data : example()
}
```